# Converting cjson json to string

Tags: c, cjson

I am using `cjson` library to create `json` and send it to server. I am using following code

```
char *string = cJSON_Print(json);
```

For which I get following output

```
{
  "type1": "car",
  "type2": "bus",
}
```

But the server expects it in string format like this

```
"{\n\t\"type1\":\t\"car\",\n\t\"type2\":\t\"bus\"\n}"
```

I am confused how can I achieve such conversion?

Comment: are you sure that what the server expects isn't the C representation of your json? or maybe there was an encoding too many...

Comment: Try  `cJSON_PrintUnformatted`. "`cJSON_Print` will print with whitespace for formatting. If you want to print without formatting, use `cJSON_PrintUnformatted`." This is from cJSON read me.

Comment: cJSON_Print will give you `"{\n\t\"type1\":\t\"car\",\n\t\"type2\":\t\"bus\"\n}"`. On printing it on stdout should look like the output you are actually getting. So, you have achieved it.